# Is there a way to test a pdo select query for at least one row found without a fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Title pretty much says it all.  If fetching is the only way to test, is there a way to reset the fetch iterator?

Comment: Typically you would do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` query if you just wanted a count. If you were going to use all the data anyways, you could also fetchAll to get all rows and get a count() of those. You can then use that returned array later in your code when you normally would just have used fetch. You might try the PDOStatement::rowCount method, but you can't really guarantee that it will return the row count for select statements as told by the manual. In some cases it might work.

Comment: Not a dup.  Asked about iterator.  I came up with this, after an initial fetch to test for any success.  while($pending_fetch || ($row = $sth->fetch ....)) { $pending_fetch = 0

Comment: Riggs please include link to what you think was dup.  I didn't find it.  I'm ready to pull the plug if there is one.  I read the one you listed.  It didn't consider iterator manipulation.

Comment: The duplicate answer suggests exactly what you selected as the correct answer here which basically states to use a `select count(*)...` statement beforehand to get a count.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, well kinda, you can perform it inline.

```
if (!$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable")->fetchColumn()) {
    echo "Ooops, didn't find anything";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The cops are after me so it'll probably get deleted.  Have the points.